# Column value of an SQL result is the name of a UDF that needs to be executed and returned in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query my database and return a table.

- The table I have contains a column with the names of user defined functions.
- I want to execute the value of the UDF column and return its result as a column in the result set of the query.

TblContainers

| ID | UID | ContainerType | Size | UDF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XXX | Chest | HUGE | udf_GetChestCount |
| 2 | YYY | Tube | SMALL | udf_GetTubeCount |
| 3 | XXX | Box | TINY | udf_GetBoxCount |

And the result set I want should look like:

| ID | ContainerType | Size | Container COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chest | HUGE | 13 (count obtained by calling udf_GetChestCount) |
| 3 | Box | TINY | 11 (count obtained by calling udf_GetBoxCount) |

Each row will have its own UDF to call in order to obtain a container count.
I am unsure how to do that last part.

I was trying to do something like the following (with @uid = 'XXX ')

```
SELECT ID, ContainerType, Size, (EXEC(UDF)(@uid) AS [ContainerCount]
FROM TblContainers WHERE UID=@uid
```

But it doesn't work for me.  How would I construct a query that will return what I need?

Comment: You would *have* to use dynamic SQL to achieve this: such requirement are normally a sure sign of a [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) in my experience.

Comment: Check the UDF returns a value and the add `SELECT` to add the returned value to the query.

Comment: Although using a `CASE` statement might be better that dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you had a single function "GetCount" that you passed the containerType to, suddenly it becomes easier.

Comment: I suggest you post the code of the two functions, presumably there is a way of optimizing them. Scalar functions are anyway a bad idea performance-wise, so we can convert them to inline table functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using a CASE statement, and direct function calls as suggested by Peter Mith and Stu. Thanks all.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetContainerCounts](@uid VARCHAR(30))    
    DECLARE @v_ID numeric;

    SET @v_UID = 'XXX'; 
    SELECT ID, ContainerType, Size, UID,
    CASE
       WHEN ContainerType = 'CHEST' THEN (call UDF)
       WHEN ContainerType = 'TUBE' THEN (call UDF)
       WHEN ContainerType = 'BOX' THEN (call UDF)               
       ELSE 0
    END AS [ContainerCount]
    FROM TBLContainers;
```

Comment: I don't see why this needs a cursor, and I don't think anyone suggested it. You could do this in a single `SELECT`